# Regarding JAXB unmarshalling for inherited classes

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, jaxb

This is regarding one of the classic problems with JAXB marshalling when dealing with marshalling/unmarshalling inherited classes. The usual solutions are to either use `@XmlSeeAlso` or to create the child class context using `JAXBContext.newInstance(child.class)`. But in our case we are dealing with a plugin-type architecture (Java ServiceLoader) wherein we do not know which plugin be loaded at runtime but the plugin's request messages extend the common RequestMessage class and response messages the ResponseMessage class. So it would not be feasible to use either of `@XmlSeeAlso` or the new context option in this case as it would tie to the plugin being created and attached.

Are there any other alternatives using JAXB itself? Or do we have to use any other JAXB alternatives like Xstream?

Thanks,
Paddy

Answer (score 0):

If the plugins are all available before you create the JAXB context, you could use class path scanning to discover the classes that directly or indirectly extend `RequestMessage` and automatically include them in the class list.

Comment: Hi @forty-two, the problem is the detection of these classes in the server side (JBoss, RestEasy) while the plugin-architecture is on the client side, thus the plugins are not available in server's classpath unless added as a runtime-time dependency, which kind of defeats the purpose of having plugins.